# How to find Resource group name from App registration in azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I would like to know how the App registration in Azure is connected to any Resource groups or any subscription as it does not show the details when click on the apps.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

No, an App registration is not an Azure Ressource but an object inside Azure AD thus there is **no relation to a resource group** there.

Comment: Thank you! then could you tell me how to find the subscription id linked to Apps inside the app registration?

Comment: Same story - an Azure AD app is also not related to an Azure Subscription. You can link an Azure AD to one or multiple Azure Subscriptions but an App registration belongs to the directory (Azure AD) and not the subscription.

Comment: so inside app registration, lets say there are 10 apps and if i want to find the app to which is linked with Subscription/ RG that could be possible right?

Comment: No, it is not possible because an app is not linked to a subscription nor a RG but only to a directory...

Comment: Thank you very much Martin for clarifying my doubts !! :) Have a good day